# Compressing StringIO data to read with pandas?

Tags: pandas, psycopg2

I have been using pandas pd.read_sql_query to read a decent chunk of data into memory each day in order to process it (add columns, calculations, etc to about 1GB of data). This has cause my computer to freeze a few times though so today I tried using psql to create a .csv file. I then zipped that file (.xz) and read it with pandas.

Overall, it was a lot smoother and it made me think about automating the process. Is it possible to replace saving a .csv.xz file and instead copying the data directly to memory while still compressing it (ideally)?

```
    buf = StringIO()

    from_curs = from_conn.cursor()
    from_curs.copy_expert("COPY table where row_date = '2016-10-17' TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", buf)
(is it possible to compress this?)
    buf.seek(0)
```

(read the buf with pandas to process it)

Comment: As you remove the freezing part by dumping on the disk, why would you not just stop there? Writing the file is stable and reading it back too, not much more required. Say why do you even compress it for 1GB?

Comment: You are probably right and that is what I am doing now. I have such big performance gains when I compress actual files that I wondered if it was possible with stringio, or if it was worthwhile just to save memory or speed things up.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the fact you have such a big gain with compressed files vs non compressed files to load the same dataframe. Would you elaborate the performance metrics you encounter? Also doy ou use spinning disks or ssd?